# Does a table <th keep track of its children?

Tags: reactjs

I have code that makes a column header `<th` of a `table` disappear. I thought that making the column header disappear would make the children of that column, the actual cells also go away. That is incorrect, at least as I coded it below.

Hard for me to believe I can't access those items and make them disappear also? I realize that I can store a map of column headers and its children, but clearly `React` must be keeping this information. So the question is, how do I access them inside `handleClick`?

```
class StockTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {hidden: [], stockItems: []};
    }
    handleClick(event) {                
        this.state.stockItems.forEach(function(stock) {               
            console.log(stock);
        });

        event.currentTarget.style.display = 'none';
        //How do I make the children of this column display style also none?
    }
    render () {                
        var items = [];
        for (var symbol in this.props.stocks) {
            var stock = this.props.stocks[symbol];

            items.push(<StockRow key={stock.symbol} stock={stock} bid={this.props.bid} ask = {this.props.ask} last={this.props.last} unwatchStockHandler={this.props.unwatchStockHandler}/>);       
                this.state.stockItems.push(stock);

        }            

        return (        
            <table table-head id="stocktable">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="maroon" />                    
                </colgroup>
                <tbody> 
                <tr>                    
                    <th></th>
                    <th onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}>P/M</th> 
                    ....
```

Comment: The `td`s in other rows *aren't* children of the `th`.

Comment: Huh? I wan the children of the table header that was clicked.

Comment: And it's not clear what you mean by that. The `th` you show a click event on doesn't have any child elements, just the text content "P/M".

Comment: I don't show the code that adds rows to the table. Be assured they are there. In a table, there is the header row, and then the rest of the rows. Are you saying that from the column header cell, there is no way to get the cells that are below in the table on the same column?

Comment: Well just *look at the markup*; cells are children of *rows*, not of *columns*. Also note that the header would generally be in `thead` not `tbody`.

Comment: Strange that it is __only__ that way. There are row operations and column operations, and you would think the semantics on column operations would also be supported by the table. I might have to either keep the map myself, or iterate over the rows[i][clickedColumn]